# Finding eigenvalue and eigenvector of non-Hermitian matrix product operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, lattice-model, tensor-network

Suppose we have a matrix product operator (MPO) $X$ with a periodic boundary, which is not necessarily Hermitian. That is, $$X^{s_1\cdots s_n}_{s^{\prime}_1\cdots s^{\prime}_n}:=\mathrm{Tr}(G_1[s_1,s_1^{\prime}]G_2[s_2,s_2^{\prime}]\cdots G_n[s_n,s^{\prime}_n]),$$
where we assume for simplicity that $s_i\in \{0,1\}$ and $s^{\prime}_i\in\{0,1\}$ for $i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$, and $G_i[\cdot,\cdot]:\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\chi\times\chi}$. Then we can regard the tensor of order $n+n$ as $2^n\times 2^n$ matrix, though it is typically too large to store in its full form.

I am interested in "low-lying excited states" of such an MPO, that is, $j$th $(j>1)$ eigenvalue and eigenvector of its matricization. Of course doing this for large $j$ is quite tough even for Hermitian cases (cf. V. Khemani *et al.* Phys. Rev. Lett. **116**, 247204 (2016)), but I suspect that there is some established way for not-so-large $j$ (such as $j=2$ or $j=3$).

Still, I haven't reached the solution. I found that ITensor has a functionality to perform DMRG targeting on low-lying excited states (https://itensor.org/docs.cgi?page=classes/dmrg), but unfortunately, the algorithm relies on a fact that the eigenvector for different eigenvalue is orthogonal, which is not true for general cases.

Are there any established methods/algorithms to deal with this situation?

Comment: As long as you can store (eigen)vectors of $X$ (i.e. vectors of size $2^n$) you can use a Krylov method.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Storage issue is exactly what I was worrying about. The assumption forces us to "decompress" the MPO into full form, which is likely to kill the benefit of MPO representations.

Comment: Which assumption?!  If you can store a vector, you can apply the MPO to it without decompressing it.  The memory requirement still grows exponentially, but with 2^n rather than 4^n, which allows you to go to (roughly) twice as big systems.

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding, but anyhow the essential difficulty (that is, the curse of dimensionality) still remains, as you mentioned. I am wondering whether it is possible to reduce the scaling of the memory requirement further than exponential. If answers, be it positive or negative, have been already provided, I would like to know that.

Comment: Well, eigenvalues of non-hermitian operators are not characterized variationally, so DMRG doesn't seem to be an option. You can use a Krylov method based on MPS.  I have the feeling this has been discussed in the past, though I'm not sure it has actually been successfully implemented.